# Adding Button to android application layout remotely

Tags: android, android-layout

Suppose i have installed an application onto my device - Now is it possible to add a button to some layout of it without redeploying the whole app using plugins/service kind of thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You app will have to have the built-in functionality to download additional interface components.

However, there is no standard way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

NO...this cant be done...
every time you need to reinstall the application on your emulator or the hardware device
there is no way you can do partial update of the application

Comment: Correct. if we had already bind to that some service (plugin kinda thing ) then we can probably try...